# ReactJS: Easily access state objects from data-reactid attributes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my first react app. I noticed that the state that contributes to an element is occasionally reflected in the reactid. Maybe it's the key that was passed?
I can't find a lot of documentation on reactid but I was wondering if there was a good way to isolate those keys.

for example, an element that I'd like to update has the ID: `.0.1.0.1.$4.3:$level.1`
The $ represent known indices of the state object I used to build that DOM node. (specifically, this is the object this.state.figures[4].level)

It would be really awesome if I could parse those $ values out with a predefined method, to make it easy to setState. Does such a thing exist?

This is me trying to setState on events defined by the top ancestor to avoid cumbersome bidirectional event handling. Am I being really foolish with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you're looking to bind events to DOM nodes based on their `data-reactid`'s?

If so - I don't think that's a wise idea at all. The `data-reactid` property is qutie transient, it changes without warning and is influenced by a number of events in the React ecosystem.

I like to think of DOM generated by React as a compile target, something I'm not really even supposed to interact with at all. A black box, if you will.

If you need help solving an eventing issue, you may want to describe that itself.

**EDIT**

You can add event handlers in React which are aware of their position in an iterator, and aware of the current state of the component.

```
<div>
  {
    things.map((thing, index) => {
      return (
        <li
          className="level"
          key={`level_${index}`}
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, thing)}>
          { thing }
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
</div>
```

So `handleClick` would receive the `thing` item when clicked, which could give you information about that particular thing. You could pass the index too. In `handleClick` you'll also have access to `this.state`.

Comment: nope. that would be unwise indeed. What I'd like to do is update the state of an element once I've targeted it with a .on handler (like this: `$(document).on('click', '.stat.level li', function(){//set some state based on the reactid of this}`)

Comment: So, you're binding an event handler to a DOM node, then when it's clicked you want to read it's react-id and set some state - what sort of state? React state? If so - why can't you bind the click handler inside the React component that's generating the ID...that way you already know the index of the element?

Comment: Isn't `this` scoped to the component? so I can change the component's state but not the state of its ancestors? It's my understanding that one needs to pass event handlers around, or use something like flux, to affect the state of distant ancestors. Is that not the case? (I know about click handlers but I also use a lot of other events like keyup and touchstart. Jquery .on feels more agile when dealing with a variety of events (but I could be wrong)

Comment: I'd certainly recommend a flux-like state management pattern if you're attempting to mutate the state of ancestor components when clicking on child components. That is what flux/redux were designed, explicitly, to solve.

Comment: the reason of ids is that react can "recconect" to the html after isomorfic (server side) rendering. To reference "dom object" react has a future called "refs"